# PackageInstaller "Silent install and uninstall of apps by Device Owner” - Android M Preview

Tags: silent-installer, kiosk-mode, android-6.0-marshmallow, device-owner, packageinstaller

PackageInstaller (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.html) seems to have been added starting in API 21 (Lollipop), however I have not found any solid code examples on how to install an APK via this API. Any code help would be appreciated.

I’m investigating COSU/Kiosk apps for Android M Preview and was trying to implement the new feature "Silent install and uninstall of apps by Device Owner” (https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#afw) via the PackageInstaller API.

Found these, but not helpful: [How to install/update/remove APK using "PackageInstaller" class in Android L?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884956/how-to-install-update-remove-apk-using-packageinstaller-class-in-android-l)
[What's "PackageInstaller" class on Lollipop, and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053200/whats-packageinstaller-class-on-lollipop-and-how-to-use-it)

Did not find any Android sample apps either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install/update/remove APK using "PackageInstaller" class in Android L?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884956/how-to-install-update-remove-apk-using-packageinstaller-class-in-android-l)

Comment: As @Kenneth mentions, it seems an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27520814/2050) provides the searched sample code.

Answer (score 14):

This is possible from Android 6.0 and up.

- Make your app the Device owner.

Once your app gets the Device owner permission, we can install, uninstall and update silently without any user intervention.

```
public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream in, String packageName)
        throws IOException {
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set params
    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
    PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
    OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    session.fsync(out);
    in.close();
    out.close();

    session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
    return true;
}


private static IntentSender createIntentSender(Context context, int sessionId) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                sessionId,
                new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE),
                0);
        return pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
    }
```

Uninstall:

```
String appPackage = "com.your.app.package";
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), getActivity().getClass());
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
PackageInstaller mPackageInstaller = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
mPackageInstaller.uninstall(appPackage, sender.getIntentSender());
```

Complete device owner demo app in this [repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/blob/5b8297e9d51983a774ba3391e28a6aa35ca3f062/app/src/main/java/com/afwsamples/testdpc/cosu/CosuUtils.java).

Comment: what is createIntentSender here..?

Comment: ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE is also undefined! is it public static String ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE = 'someString' or specific android constant?

Comment: Not android specific.. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/ check this sample app.

Comment: Please note that you must add android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES to your manifest for the uninstall to work (tested on Api level 22 or under)

Comment: @benchuk you can delete packages below 22 API? without root?

Comment: @amalBit mmmm, I am not sure, because my test app has root permissions... did not try it without root. but I assume it will not work or it will be a security issue.

Comment: @benchuk this solution is for apps running on non rooted phones. So device owner permission is enough to handle it.

Comment: Why it's not possible below Android 6.0 ?

Comment: @woprandi The device owner api supports silent install/uninstall from Android 6.0 and above.

Comment: @amalBit Ok because I tested on Lollipop without any runtime error so I didn't understand. Thanks

Comment: ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE = "cm.android.intent.action.INSTALL_COMPLETE"

Comment: I have a problem with Android 10... the PlayProtect popup appears so I can't have a "silent" installation. Does a workaround exist for this?

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro I am not aware if there is any change in behaviour for a device owner app. Is your app made the device owner app?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out, here's the code:

```
    try
    {
        PackageInstaller pi = app.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
        int sessId          = pi.createSession(new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL));

        PackageInstaller.Session session = pi.openSession(sessId);

        // .. write updated APK file to out


        long sizeBytes = 0;
        final File file = new File(filepathApk);
        if (file.isFile())
        {
            sizeBytes = file.length();
        }

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        in = new FileInputStream(filepathApk);
        out = session.openWrite("my_app_session", 0, sizeBytes);

        int total = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            total += c;
            out.write(buffer, 0, c);
        }
        session.fsync(out);
        in.close();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("InstallApkViaPackageInstaller - Success: streamed apk " + total + " bytes");

        // fake intent
        Context app = this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(app, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmtest = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(app,
                1337111117, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        session.commit(alarmtest.getIntentSender());
        session.close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What 'AlarmReceiver' class does?